# Storing dataframes in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm trying to store a bunch of dataframes in a list, and each of these dataframes has column names that are important (they are stock names, which are different for each dataframe).

I'm storing them in a list because this way it can be done with a foreach loop, which will allow me to run this beforehand, then use the list as a database of information.

right now I have:

```
Y.matrices <- foreach(i = (1:600)) %dopar% {
  df = data.frame(data)
  return(df)
}
```

The issue with this is once I store them, I'm not sure how to get the data frames back.  If I do:

```
unlist(Y.matrices[1])
```

I get a long numeric vector that has lost the column names.  Is there some other way to store these data frames (ie, perhaps not in a list) that would enable me to preserve the formats?

Thanks!

Comment: If `Y.matrices` is a `list`, then use `Y.matrices[[1]]`

Comment: Wow I did not realize that - so what's the difference between Y.matrices[1] and Y.matrices[[1]]?

Answer (score 1):

To access 1 individual dataframe, you can use `Y.matrices[[#]]`, where `#` is the dataframe you want to access, if the result needs to be 1 merged dataframe with all the 600 dataframes you can use:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- bind_rows(Y.matrices, .id = "df")
```

The .id fills in the number of the data.frame, or if they are named in the list, the name of the dataframe.